# Which universe has more entropy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, entropy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-constant

Lets say I have $2$ universes with [fluid stress energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid) tensors:

$$T_1^{\mu \nu} = (\rho + p/c^2) u^\mu u^\nu + p g^{ \mu \nu} + \Lambda_1 g^{ \mu \nu}$$

$$T_2^{\mu \nu} = (\rho + p/c^2) u^\mu u^\nu + p g^{ \mu \nu} + \Lambda_2 g^{ \mu \nu}$$

where $\rho$ is the density, $p$ is the pressure, $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant, $g^{\mu \nu}$ is the metric and $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the stress energy tensor. If $\Lambda_1> \Lambda_2$ then which stress energy tensor has more entropy? Assume low temperature. Personally I'm confused if variants of relations such as: $\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\Delta p_x\Delta p_y\Delta p_z $ are equiprobable where $x$, $y$, $z$ are the positions axis and $p_x$, $p_y$,  $p_z$ are the momentum axis are applicable.

Comment: Which definition of entropy are you using?

Comment: I was personally thinking of thermodynamic entropy.

Comment: I think, the discussions in chapter 8 and 9 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0605010) will be helpful. One can also try to define entropy in gravitational field using Bel-Robinson tensor , as it has been motivated in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5612.pdf) article